# Check my proof of how I arrived at my answer

Tags: logic

Show proof for:

$$(P \to Q), P \vee (\neg\neg R \wedge \neg\neg Q), (S \to \neg R), \neg (P \wedge Q) \vdash (\neg S \vee  \neg Q)$$

is this correct?

1. $(P \to Q) \ \ $           Premise
2. $P \vee (\neg\neg R \wedge \neg\neg Q) \ \ $           Premise
3. $(S \to \neg R) \ \ $           Premise
4. $\neg (P \wedge Q) \ \ $           Premise
5. $(P \to (P \wedge Q)) \ \ $       1, Abs (Absorption)
6. $P \vee (R \wedge Q) \ \ $               2, DN (Double Negation )
7. $(\neg S \vee R) \ \ $           3, Impl (Implication)
8. $( \neg P \vee  \neg Q) \ \ $                   4, DeM (De Morgan’s Theorem)
9. $\neg S \ \ $               7, DS (Disjunctive Syllogism)
10. $\neg Q \ \ $              8, DS (Disjunctive Syllogism)
11. $\neg S \vee \neg Q \ \ $          9, 10 Add (Addition)

Comment: Hi, I have some trouble parsing your notation. When you write P ^ Q, which operation does that signify? Also, when you write $X,Y:Z$, do you mean $X, Y \vdash Z$ respectively $X,Y \models Z$? Lastly, what logical calculus are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Steps (7), (9), and (10) are wrong.

- Step 7 problem: $(S \rightarrow \lnot R)$ turns into $\color{blue}{(\lnot S \lor \lnot R)}$, not $\color{red}{(\lnot S \lor R)}$
- Step 9 problem: $(\lnot S \lor R)$ alone will not give you $\lnot S$ by disjunctive syllogism
- Step 10 problem: see the problem for step 9

Here's one way of proving what you want to prove (in a Fitch-style system).

<kbd>1</kbd> $~~P \rightarrow Q~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ hyp
 <kbd>2</kbd> $~~P \lor (\lnot\lnot R \land \lnot\lnot Q)~~~$ hyp
 <kbd>3</kbd> $~~S \rightarrow \lnot R~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ hyp
 <kbd>4</kbd> $~~\lnot(P \land Q)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ hyp

<kbd>5</kbd> $~~~~~|~~ P~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ hyp
   $~~~~~|~~ ------$
 <kbd>6</kbd> $~~~~~|~~ Q~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ *modus ponens* 1, 5
 <kbd>7</kbd> $~~~~~|~~ P \land Q~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ $\land$-introduction 6, 5
 <kbd>8</kbd> $~~~~~|~~ \bot~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ $\bot$-introduction 7, 4
 
 <kbd>9</kbd> $~~~~~|~~ \lnot S \lor \lnot Q~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ $\bot$-elimination 8

<kbd>10</kbd> $~~~~~|~~ \lnot\lnot R \land \lnot\lnot Q~~~~~~~~$ hyp
   $~~~~~|~~ ------$
<kbd>11</kbd> $~~~~~|~~ \lnot\lnot R~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ $\land$-elimination 10
<kbd>12</kbd> $~~~~~|~~ R~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ $\lnot\lnot$-elimination 11
<kbd>13</kbd> $~~~~~|~~ \lnot S~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ *modus tollens* 12, 3
<kbd>14</kbd> $~~~~~|~~ \lnot S \lor \lnot Q~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ $\lor$-introduction 13

<kbd>15</kbd> $~~\lnot S \lor \lnot Q~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ $\lor$-elimination 10-14, 5-9, 2